# Login directly to terminal instead of GUI

Tags: macos, terminal, login-screen

First: I'm obviously not talking about logging in and then automatically launching Terminal.app.

In [older versions of Mac OS X](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20020318020806482), you used to be able to type `>console` in the username field on the login screen and go directly into a command line terminal session.

I haven't done it in years until the other day. However, now, when I try it, my computer just locks up. I can't cancel, and it never sends me to a terminal session.

Is it even possible to do this anymore? If not, does anybody know when it was removed? It seems odd that typing `>console` would cause the machine to lock up if it wasn't recognizing it in some way.

Comment: what OS are you running?

Comment: I have the same problem on a MBA 2013 running OS X 10.9.1

Comment: This is Mavericks on a 2012 Retina MBP with a clean install from only two weeks ago.

Comment: Strange, the testing I did was with OS X 10.9.1 on a mini, MBP has 10.7.5 and a MB 10.8. Hope someone else has a better clue.  Have you tried apple support? Reinstall?

Comment: It's a very fresh install with a bunch of developer setup, so I'd prefer not to reinstall. If I can't figure anything out soon, I may try the Genius Bar.

Comment: I tried this in 10.8.5, and the screen flashed gray then the login screen returned. No lockup.  But being able to log in without a password seems like a security hole.

Comment: MacBook Air running 10.10.1 I got it to work 1 out of 10 times and locked up the machine and had to force reboot each and every other time. iMac running 10.95 I got it to work consistently. It might be a 10.10 thing.

Comment: I can confirm this is NOT working on 10.10.1. We have a 2010 iMac, a 2012 MacMini, and a 2014 MacBook Pro, all running 10.10.1, all fresh installs, none worked! We didn't even get a 1/10 working as a previous poster did. Every time, on every Mac, it goes right into the blank/black screen then locks the machine.

Comment: Looks like we aren't the only ones with the problem https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6691824

Answer (score 7):

If you find >console not working, newer OS have disabled it by default.

A quick command line modification of the preference will re-enable it:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist "DisableConsoleAccess" NO
```

Comment: This does not work on `10.12.1 (16B2555)`

Comment: Nor does it work on 10.13.2

Comment: any solution for Monterey OSX?

Answer (score 6):

### >console works on OS X 10.7.5 , 10.8 and 10.9

I have just tested `>console` and was able to log into the console without issues running the above OS X's.

I would say there is something else wrong with your system if you cannot get to the basic console.

I would also check your console logs and activity monitor as specified [here](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3353).

Comment: The OP could even ssh into their Mac before attempting the >console log in attempt and then tail the system log file! run sysdiagnose when the Mac is frozen and otherwise see what process is stuck or running. My question is what needs to be done in single user mode that you can't accomplish from ssh or terminal app.

Answer (score 3):

Another thing you might want to check is if you can boot in single user mode.  Single user mode is triggered by holding cmd-s at startup:

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1492

The single-user mode environment is quite a bit different than the standard terminal, because you login as root and a lot of system services are turned off, so it is not equivalent to the `>console` approach.

Comment: Yep, I can get into Single user mode just fine. If it's any different, my screen now turns gray and *then* locks up after typing `>console` at the login screen.

Comment: Hmmm.  Have you made sure to try it after a full restart, not just a user logout?  And just to throw out some more random ideas, have you installed the newest XQuartz?  You could also check your [tty file](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/h/348) to make sure everything looks in order, but be careful that you know how to reverse any changes you make.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue and can add the following:

sshed into the machine prior to entering >console at the login window.

Entered >console and hit return at the login window.

On the machine that was connected via ssh I ran sudo tail /var/log/system.log which showed evidence of a SecurityAgent crash.

killed (kill -HUP ) the WindowServer process (via ssh) and immediately got a white block in the top left corner of the screen. I hit Return and was at the login: prompt and was able to authenticate and work in console mode.

Subsequent tests have all been the same so in order to access >console it looks as if you need a second machine and ssh access.