# Typing >console in username box—nothing shows up until cancelled

Tags: macos, terminal, login

When I type `>console` into the username box on the login screen, the computer seems to freeze for a very long time. Then I press `^C^C^C^C^D^C^D^D^D^C^D` and eventually the computer unfreezes—but first, it flashes the session contents (showing the login console prompt, in what appears to be the same font as single user mode).

This is a fresh (or close enough) Mavericks install with

- no third-party kernel extensions
- no extra apps but the Yosemite installer (It is the same on Yosemite but I'm not allowed to ask about that :P)

on a Macbook Air, 2012, 10.9.3.

It appears that I'm having a problem very similar to the one in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119027/login-directly-to-terminal-instead-of-gui) … but the console actually shows up for me, as soon as I exit.

Also, I am using the user list then selecting a name and pressing <kbd>option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>return ↩</kbd> but that doesn't seem to matter.

---

I was able to take a photo of what is going on:

```
Darwin/BSD (Hostname.local) (console)

login: █username>
Password:**** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Suspend -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0xf400 ****

Password:
Password:
Login incorrect
login: █D ––that is a control-d
```

The block characters are cursors.

A session that I could actually log in to (but still not see my typing):

```
Darwin/BSD (Hostname.local) (console)

login: <username>
Password:
Last login: Tue Jun 24 08:06:36 on console
$ echo hello
hello
$
$
$ **** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Suspend -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0xf400 ****

$
$ logout
█
```

Comment: Alright, I tried it again and this time it showed up with the login prompt but nothing echoed until logout.

Comment: Is this a question? It looks more like a report of strange behaviour

Comment: Are you using an external display?

Comment: @Matt: Yes. I should have mentioned that (but I haven't tested it with only one yet).

Comment: @0942v8653: If you can, test it without the ED. I've noticed that sometimes >console mode and SU mode don't play nicely with ED's.

Answer (score 1):

This account is reserved for the graphical log in screen to shutter you to the command line environment / minimal text terminal. It’s not an actual account you can use to log in to the OS, just a signal to switch from one set of processes and interface to another.

That being said, I wonder if something is up and you have an actual account you are loggin in as, and not typing terminal a second time. Can you reproduce this on a clean install on an external USB drive? You might just need to reinstall the OS or examine the system log for errors at the time you try to log in.