# >console login on macOS High Sierra 10.13.5

Tags: macos, high-sierra, console

In attempting to log in using >console, I am met with a black screen and no terminal prompt, I eventually need to reboot into the GUI. I have successfully used this in the past (say, Mavericks). Has anyone been successful in >console login using High Sierra? I would rather not have to dual boot into linux. Disabling SIP does not solve the problem. The command: 
`sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist "DisableConsoleAccess" NO` does nothing. To update this, I contacted Apple regarding this and have a macOS engineer working on a fix. When I hear back, I will update the OP.

Comment: From the top voted answer here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119027/login-directly-to-terminal-instead-of-gui, it appears that the >console login method does not work on versions of macOS after Mavericks (10.9).

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I am trying to understand why.

Comment: The above question is different because I am seeking to resolve this issue on macOS. The previous answer is not a solution to the OP problem, but a workaround which most users won't ever use. I have edited the original post to include my contact with Apple macOS engineers.