# How to access console mode in macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, beta, big-sur

I can't login using the [>console trick](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119027/login-directly-to-terminal-instead-of-gui) to disable the GUI on macOS Big Sur. 
Is there any other way to use macOS Big Sur in console mode?

Comment: The linked question has several answers, some of them explain how to enable it again. Did you try them all?

Comment: Yes I've tried them all, except the ssh one since I don't have another device available right now.

Comment: The ssh thing doesn't work for me, because trying to type it in just gives me an error as if I'd put the wrong password in